# SwiftUI TextField Causing Memory Leaks

Tags: swiftui, memory-leaks

I've been tracking down a memory leak problem in my project for a number of days now and have seemed to isolated it to views using a TextField. When using a TextField in a view, navigating away and then back to the view causes a memory leak to show up in Instruments.

The project contains multiple navigation links and is working with core data, but I was able to reproduce the problem using a minimal project with two navigation links and no core data.  The links navigate to a simple view containing a Text item and a TextField both referring to a single @State variable. Navigating between the two views without entering any data into the TextField is sufficient to trigger the leak in Instruments. Commenting out the TextField with no other changes prevents the leak from showing up.

The minimal project was created for Multiplatform with the leak found using macOS for the target (didn't try any iOS targets as not working them right now). Xcode version is 13.2.1. Deployment target is macOS 12.0. Running on a MacBook Pro with Monterey version 12.2 Beta.

Here's the code for the Content view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink("Link 1", destination: TestView())
                NavigationLink("Link 2", destination: TestView())
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

And for the TestView:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var testString = "Hello, world!"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(testString)
            TextField("Test", text: $testString)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

When just running under Xcode I also noted occasionally the debug area showing the message "onChange(of: Bool) action tried to update multiple times per frame." No idea why that's happening either, though it seems independent of whether the TextField is present or not.

If anyone could tell me what/why this is happening and if I should worry about these leaks or not I would greatly appreciate it.

Added 12/30/21: I tried replacing the TextField with TextEdit and the memory leak no longer showed up when shifting between views.

Also 12/30/21: reference should have been to using TextEditor, not TextEdit.

Comment: any luck on this? I've got a similar problem when using a text field in my view

Comment: Not really. I was never successful in completely eliminating the issue so pretty much gave up trying on my own. From what I could see seems to be an issue internal to Swift rather than something I could do anything about other than not use text fields. But I'm not very experienced so was hoping someone else might be able to give more info. No luck so far on that either...

Comment: I'm experiencing something similar with a TextEditor in a mac app but only on Sonoma, on Ventura works. My view opens in a popover and when i click outside it closes and then i nil the viewModel that is tied to the popover, but it never deallocates and onDisappear is not called on the views. When i commented the TextEditor and it deallocates, however i think i'll not be able to reproduce it on a blank project

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing this issue when using an apple pencil and the TextField with an .onSubmit modifier. If I use an on screen keyboard there is no leak.

I found that when I added .keyboardType(.numberPad) to the TextField the issue was resolved.